# When will XmlHttpResponse.responseText be filled with reponse from the server?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I wrote the following simple javascript code

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
    <head> <title>ajax</title> </head>
    <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            var url = "http://localhost/javascript/test.php";
            xhr.open("GET", url);
            alert(xhr);
            xhr.send(null);
            xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {alert("change");}
            alert(xhr.responseText);
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

the result shows xhr.responseText is empty.
But following javascript code works fine. Why?

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
    <head><title>ajax</title></head>
    <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            var url = "http://localhost/javascript/test.php";
            xhr.open("GET", url);
            xhr.send(null);
            xhr.onreadystatechange = 
            function () { 
                 if (xhr.readyState == 4) alert(xhr.responseText); 
            };
    </script>
    </body>

    </html>
```

Following is the simple PHP code: test.php

```
    <?php
    echo date("F j, Y, H:i:s");
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When an answer comes from the server, the browser will fire the object's onreadystatechanged event, causing the function you attached to it, to be fired, what you need to do in your first example is  put this line :

```
alert(xhr.responseText);
```

inside the function you attach to the onreadystatechanged event.
otherwise the browser will just process the line immediately after sending the request. 
In addition, you must check that the readystate is 4 (4: request finished and response is ready), and its also worth it to check that the status is 200, which means that everything's ok.

Comment: I attached **function () {alert("change");}** to the onreadystatechange event, so when readystate changes, an alert window pops up, then I click OK, then readystate changes again, another alert window pops up, I click it again . After 4 clicks, the readystate == 4, then I should get the responseText now.

Comment: Not at all! Because, Immediately after attaching that function, the browser executed the line:
alert(xhr.resonseText);
and will never go back to that again, if, after four clicks, you would like that line to execute, you must put it between the {} of the function you attach to onreadystatechanged.
all the best!

Answer (score 0):

Similar to r0nny's answer, your first example gets processed before your ajax called has been returned.  Using the `onreadystatechange` waits for the ajax response, then does what you need it to.